# How to make a sequence of elements that can check if the one before it is active?

Tags: jquery, web, element

This is extremely complicated to explain with words but I'm trying to make a system where I have one element (number 1 in the image) that stems of to another element. In some cases like element two it might stem of in two directions. I want to be able to activate these elements but only if an element linked to it is activated.

[image: Bead example]

Example:

The element to the right of element two can now be activated but if element two wasn't active I would have to activate element one first.

I thought of using data-attributes and give them a number and check if a number before that was active, but the problem is when sometimes it divides into two, three or more. Is there any way I could achieve this? Any suggestion would be great I just can't come up with a way of detecting this condition, thanks in advance!

Additional info:

The basic idea is that there has to be a touching element active (dark blue) before you can activate that element. In the image below you can see two different ways of reaching element A, also looking at the dark blue lines you can see what other elements are now available for activating.

[image]

Comment: there isn't enough information to know what rules are when bracnches split, or how to handle loops

Comment: @charlietfl Added more info.

Comment: for what it's worth I like puzzles like this and worked up a demo using table cells. I used a table because could make the html easily with script http://jsfiddle.net/L6b2C/1/ Something in this is bound to help you

Comment: Thanx charlie that looks really interesting I'm gonna have a look :D

Answer (score 2):

I'd recommend building a graph on page load, and then using this graph through the lifetime of the page to track what has been activated etc.

A basic node of your graph would look like this:

```
var node = {
   adjacent : [], // list of adjacent nodes (depending on your use case, you might not need this
   previous : prevNode, // previous node (for node2, it is node1)
   isActive : false,
   activate : function(){ 
       // code that checks previous and activates the current node
       // if previous is not active, it can call previous.activate()
       // which will then activate prevNode and its dependencies
   }
}
```

Comment: This sounds great, but would that mean I have to hard code all the nodes with the adjacent nodes? and when you say a graph, Ive never made a graph before without the use of a plugin. Is there a way of doing that or do you mean just like the example?

Comment: a) You don't have to hardcode. Depending on how your HTML is laid out, you might be able to build it by traversing the DOM. (b) You'd build a tree by defining nodes like above. You'd only keep a reference to the root node (node1). Other nodes will be referenced via the root node.

Comment: Thanks I'm going to try that out now.